# CSS media query for small screen overwriting media query for large screen

Tags: screen, media

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T2bj0.png)

As you can see in the image I have written a query for a screen with a width of 768px but the query I wrote for a device with a width of 375px is getting applied.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2961P.png)

I tried using max-width but I would have to rewrite it again for all device widths which would be time consuming. I made sure to add them in order from highest pixel width to lowest pixel width after the general css.

Comment: what problem you encountered with `max-width`

Comment: I resolved the problem and the problem with max width was I would have to repeat the same lines of code in 375px for 768px making a lot of repeatitions of the same code.

Comment: standard is do mobile first version without media query and one desktop media query

Comment: if you have a lot of repeating code use some css preprocesor mixins (or utility classes, but it's different long story)

Answer (score 1):

you are using two media queries with only min-width boundary

- `@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {...}` lets call it desktop
- `@media screen and (min-width: 375px) {...}` lets call it mobile

if these block should applied only on distinct resolutions, use `min` and `max` with 1 pixel difference:

- desktop `@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {...}`
- mobile `@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {...}`